Unable add existing NIC to new vm using azure bicep
I have tried attach existing nic to vm while redeployment using azure bicep. it's not attaching old one & creating and attaching new nic to vm. Please help how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance
Please sample code to fix this issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
